# Is there a holomorphic diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}P^{2n+1}$ without fixed point?

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, projective-space

Is there a holomorphic diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}P^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{C}P^{2n+1}$ without fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The holomorphic diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb C P^n$ are $PGL_{n+1}$. These always have fixed points because every matrix has an eigenvector.